# Correct way to represent repeated data in stream

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

Any advice on how to support `repeated` messages? Specifically, if these message are all one type. In JSON, these would essentially be an array. In my case, I do not care about indexing however, but that is not saying that an array type would not be useful for protobuf. I have considered the below approaches, but I don' like the tradeoff's. It ins't clear from reading the Google documentation which approach is meant to be used for collections.

1. Use any existing message and just have a bunch of empty fields

   You can use an existing type and just only include the desired collection of repeated messages. So if a user message type has repeated photo message type, send an empty user with nothing but the photo collection field.
2. Create a wrapper type

   This is what #1 does but instead of using an existing type, create a new one. This is a little cleaner because it is explicit and doesn't use empty fields. Still has message typing too. In photo case, this would be an ArrayOfPhotos message w/ only repeated photo message field.
3. Use delimited stream

   Not too sure about this method as I haven't tried it, but protobuf supports delimiting streams. This seems cool, but I would imagine it has downside of less strong typing. Streams could contain a grab bag of different message types.

   Does seem beneficial though that this option requires no extra Message types.

   In photo case, this would be delimited photo messages, but again, seems like you could throw user messages in as well.

Comment: What is your real problem? Reading your question is like walking into the middle of a discussion; there is no context to help with possible tradeoffs. I infer from the tag that it somehow involves protobuf, but that's not enough.

Comment: That said, the usual approach to eliminating transmission of duplicate data is to retain a reference to the already-sent data and then send the reference rather than the data. Physically implementing this in protobuf would involve unions. But there are pitfalls to this approach, as you can see with Java serialization.

Comment: @kdgregory yes, tags are meant for you to infer from. My question is the correct way to represent repeated data in protobufs. I have given as much context as possible on the tradeoff's of different approaches. Now I am interested in hearing your approaches as well as an answer as to which approach is correct. Google does not seem to answer this anywhere in their docs.

Comment: @kdgregory maybe the confusion is because I started off with my approaches rather than my question, I have edited the question and hopefully it is now more clear what is being asked.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to ask what to do when your *top-level* data is an array rather than a record. (It isn't totally clear from your question whether you're asking about top-level, but otherwise I don't understand the problem.)

The questions to ask yourself are:

1. Is there any chance that some day you'll want to add some auxiliary data to this message which is not attached to any one of the objects? For instance, maybe your list of photos will some day have an album name attached. In this case, you certainly want to use your solution #2, since it gives you the flexibility to add other fields later without messing up some existing message type.
2. Will it be a problem for the client or the server to have to hold the entire data set in memory and parse/serialize it all at once? This is a requirement for a single message. For example, if you're sending 1GB of photos, you probably want each end to be able to handle one or just a few photos at a time. In this case you certainly want solution #3.

I would not advise using solution #1 in any case.